Flask session not saved
app.secret_key = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY', 'default_secret_key')
@app.route("/login", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def login():
username = request.json.get("username")
passcode = request.json.get("passcode")

print(username)
print(passcode)

cur = mysql.connection.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = %s", (username,))

rows = cur.fetchall()

print(rows)

def check_user(username,passcode):

    if not username:
        return False, "Please enter username"
    
    if not passcode:
        return False, "Please enter passcode"
    
    if len(rows) != 1 or not check_password_hash(rows[0]["hash_passcode"], passcode):
        return False, "Invalid username and/or passcode"
    
    return True, "Logged In"

checked, message = check_user(username, passcode)


session["user_id"] = rows[0]["user_id"]
session.modified = True  # <-- Add this
print(session.get("user_id"))


if checked:

        return jsonify({"authenticated" : True, "message" : message}), 200
    
return jsonify({"authenticated" : False, "message" : message}), 400

@app.route("/add", methods=["POST")
 def add():
    print(session.get("user_id")) //result is None


I don't know why this happen, I've try to config everything but still not work. I'm working      with React and Flask.


Can you provide more information? Because from what I'm seeing I can only guess some solutions. Make sure that you have your secret_key. Please run it with debugger to get more information because there is nothing to go off at the moment.
